# Trying to find a movie - before 90's

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a movie I heard in movie forums, From 2005 - 2010, more than two dozen people had claimed that they watched it on local TV in 90's.

Strangely, nobody remembered its name.

I would say there's possibility that this is just their imagination, but I'm willing to give a try.

It looks like it's some experimental movie or experimental-like. A woman was locked inside an abandoned factory with a bald man, also there're many plastic models. He only drink boiled water, when he cries there will be blood come out of his eyes instead of tears. His presence is torturing the woman but she always failed to escape.

In the end someone came to pick up the woman. When she thought she's free that 'someone' shot her. Using a pistol.

The bald man came, and went back to factory with the dying woman in his arms.

Someone recalled that its name has something linked to "alien" or something. Not sure of this.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TearsOfBlood

Comment: Can you link to any of the movie forums where people discussed it? Maybe there'd be some additional clues there.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: It's obviously some psychopathic rip-off of Misery. lol